# Disabling Meteor 2 minute server timeout?

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

How can one remove/increase the server side connection timeout from Meteor when using server side routes with Iron Router?

There is a fix when using vanilla Node: https://contourline.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/preventing-server-timeout-in-node-js/

But I cannot figure out where to put the code in the above sample to make it work with Meteor and Iron Router

Here's a sample route:

```
Router.route('veryslowroute', {
  path: '/veryslow',
  where: 'server',
  action: function () {
    // Route never rendered in browser. Reducing value here to 110000 will render just fine
    Meteor._sleepForMs(120000);
    // These I've tried:
    // this.response.setTimeout(0);
    // this.response.connection.setTimeout(0);
    // this.response.connection.server.setTimeout(0);
    this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    this.response.end(JSON.stringify({
      key: 'Sorry for being so slow'
    }));
  }
});
```

So it appears the timeout needs to be set somewhere else. Anybody?

EDIT: It appears that this isn't about NodeJS but Meteor itself, likely the webapp-package. Still couldn't find a workaround. Same thing happens when using webapp directly without Iron Router.

EDIT: Now there is an issue in Meteor: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3826

Comment: To my surprise this.response.setTimeout(9999999999999999), worked for me.

Comment: I'm running into an issue where the server side process takes so long to finish and send a response, the client receives and error.  I give setTimeout a shot.  Thanks!